# Strange int output in C

Tags: c, printf

I am using OpenCV and I need to convert Iplimage->ID to char[ ] so that I can send it using TCP and then reconvert it to int on the server.

Here is the Iplimage header:

```
typedef struct _IplImage
{
    int  nSize;
    int  ID;  //<--- ID of type INT
    int  nChannels;
    int  alphaChannel;
    int  depth;
    char colorModel[4];
    char channelSeq[4];
    int  dataOrder;
    int  origin;
    int  align;
    int  width;
    int  height;
    struct _IplROI *roi;
    struct _IplImage *maskROI;
    void  *imageId;
    struct _IplTileInfo *tileInfo;
    int  imageSize;
    char *imageData;
    int  widthStep;
    int  BorderMode[4];
    int  BorderConst[4];
    char *imageDataOrigin;
}
IplImage;
```

this is my code:

```
char IDbuffer[10];
snprintf(IDbuffer,10,"%e",frame->ID);//where frame is of type IplImage*
printf("frame->ID= %a\n",IDbuffer);
```

and this what I got printed:

> frame->ID= 0x0.0000000037d0cp-1022

even trying

```
printf("frame->ID= %a\n",frame->ID);
```

give me the same output.

Is this an integer format ?? and if yes how could I convert the char * of this format to an int??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about using the correct format specifiers? For int that is `%d`. To print a string use `%s`.

Comment: Please read your manual page before posting here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `%d` format specifier since `frame->ID` is an integer:

```
snprintf(IDbuffer,10,"%d",frame->ID);
```

And then use the `%s` format specifier to print the buffer:

```
printf("frame->ID= %s\n",IDbuffer);
```

There's more information about the format specifiers in [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) man page.

Comment: using printf("frame->ID= %s\n",IDbuffer); give me an output: 0, 
while using printf("frame->ID= %d\n",IDbuffer); give an output -511415808
What is the correct one ??

Comment: @AhmedKato maybe the frame ID is zero ?

Comment: @AhmedKato try `printf("frame->ID= %d\n", frame->ID);` first

Comment: could you please give me a reference for the difference between format specifiers ??

Comment: @AhmedKato I did, check the link in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`%e` format specifier requires an argument of type `double`, while you are passing an `int` instead. The resultant behavior is undefined. That's all there is to it.

By using `%e` you are making a promise to `snprintf`. You promise that you will supply a `double` argument in the corresponding position. Later you break that promise by supplying an `int` instead of `double`, which leads to a meaningless result. You are essentially lying to `snprintf` about the type of `frame->ID`.

`%a` also requires a `double` argument. Why do you insist on using `double` format specifiers with a `int` argument? How do you expect this to work?

Either supply an argument of correct type (which is `double`), or use the proper format specifier (which is `%d` for `int`). Either this or that. Mixing things up like you do will not achieve anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need cast `ID` to double before printing it:

```
snprintf(IDbuffer,10,"%e", (double)frame->ID);
```

Alternatively, you can print it as integer:

```
snprintf(IDbuffer,10,"%d", frame->ID)
```

Check this for more information on [snprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)